# converting 4byte hex string to integer

Tags: c++, mfc, hex, strtol

I am trying to do a conversion from hex string to integer in a MFC project.
The code is like this:

```
CString sMask = "0xFFFFFFE0";
char* pMaskBuffer   = sMask.GetBuffer(sMask.GetLength());               
sMask.ReleaseBuffer();
char * p = NULL;
long iMask = strtol(pMaskBuffer, &p, 16);
```

The code was working fine when sMask variable was small.But 4 byte mask is generating strange values. Instead of 4294967264 , i am getting 2147483647. How to overcome this. Help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the strtol returns long use  this

```
unsigned long iMask = strtoul(pMaskBuffer, &p, 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you ReleaseBuffer **after** use. You program has Undefined Behaviour

> The address returned by GetBuffer is invalid after the call to ReleaseBuffer or any other CString operation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300574(v=vs.60).aspx

As people have explained, you want `unsigned long` parsing.

Answer (score 1):

From a [`std::strtol` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol):

> If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, a range error occurs (setting [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) to `ERANGE`) and `LONG_MAX`, `LONG_MIN`, ... is returned.

In your case `LONG_MAX` is returned, and if you check `errno` I'll bet it's going to be `ERANGE`. The reason being that `strtol` is for *signed* values, if you want unsigned values you should use [`std::strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul).

---

Also note, if you sometime in the future change to use the C++11 function [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), it will throw an [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception in this case.